# java streams - collect elements from map of collections using condition on the values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map. Let's say

Map> 
I want to collect all the long values (keys)
when at least one myObj answers

```
myObj.isEnabled=false
```

using java stream.

I tried

```
map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry->entry.getValue().stream().filter(x->!x.isEnabled())).findAny().collect()
```

Comment: Why did you try that? How does it achieve your goal or what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Long> keys = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(o -> !o.isEnabled()))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives me List<Map.Entry<Long, List<MyObj>>> collect . How do I collect it to a map? (Collectors.toMap doesnt seem like it)

Comment: @rails My bad, fixed.

Comment: @rail Wait, did you want to collect a list of keys, or a map with filtered entries?